# Apply Angular directive on template of other directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using Angular-UI tabs directive.
It converts that layout:

```
<tabset class="incidents-manage-tabs">
    <tab>
         <tab-heading>HEADER</tab-heading>
         TAB CONTENT
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

to

```
<div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" ng-transclude="">
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane ng-scope active" tab-content-transclude="tab" ng-class="{active: tab.active}">
            TAB CONTENT
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I writing directive for custom scrollbar, i need to apply that directive on the ".tab-content" div that is generated by the tabs directive, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add directive attribute (or tag, or class..) in your other directive template and it will work. When AngularJS replaces some elements with your custom directives, it compiles template code, that means that it goes through all template code and matches other directives, it replaces the directive with template and repeats that process until there is nothing to replace (yeah, you can have recursive directives easily).

Comment: My directive applies as attribute, so i need to add it to element that is not exists in the markup of the tabs. so where can i put it?

Comment: You can wrap `TAB CONTENT` with another `div` with your attribute, that should work.

Comment: than i need to add scroller to each of the wrappers, instead of just aplly one scroller on the tab-content